# How to measure I/O performance of ramdisk (/dev/ram0)?

Tags: performance

Can we measure I/O performance of ramdisk(/dev/ram0) ?

AFAIK I/O performance can be measured using 'dd' command.

Eg:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ramdisk0/file bs=1k count=200
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the ramdisk is on the same machine where you are going to have to run the loads, there will be some bias towards reporting slower performance as you increase the load, but...

Measure the time it takes to execute 1 dd write, as described above, over perhaps 10 runs.  Do the same for reads, but watch out for outliers as the cache warms.

Do the same for 2, 3, 4, ... dd writes simultaneously, until the time start to increase rapidly, but ***keep on testing*** until the response time is about 10 times what you measured initially.

Now plot response times against load. You should get a curve that looks like a hockey-stick, i.e. "_/" so you can plot load against performance for the device.

--dave

Comment: I guess I expected to see a higher MB/s from a RAM disk, when comparing against NVMe. The tmpfs isn't really that much faster from a top-class NVMe, at least when BS=512K. This `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/rd/file.dat bs=512K count=5000` "only" gave me 4.8GBs (i3 7100, 2400MHz memory)

Answer (score 1):

For Write:

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/ram/test bs=1048576 count=4096 oflag=nocache conv=fsync

For Read:

dd if=/dev/shm/ram/test of=/dev/null bs=1048576 iflag=nocache,sync conv=nocreat

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
hdparm -Tt /dev/ram0
```

You should consider using tmpfs rather than ramdisk